# Ionic 4: Action Sheet css issue

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Ionic4 action sheet controller not taking up CSS.

This is my ts code

```
 const actionSheet = await this.actionSheetController.create({
      mode: 'md',
      cssClass: 'match-item-action-sheet red',
      buttons: [{ ...
      }]
    });
```

And here is my CSS class

```
.match-item-action-sheet{
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.red{
    color:red;
}
```

Here is the live code https://ionic-v4-xbwrsj.stackblitz.io/action-sheet

Below is the expected behavior with class `match-item-action-sheet`
[image]

Comment: can you srt your relevant code in stackblitz fork and show us link:https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4

Comment: Have you check your given class is adding or not to the html?

Comment: @לבנימלכה I have edited my question and added the link at the bottom of the question

Comment: @SagarKodte no it is not getting added

Answer (score 1):

Use `::ng-deep` in css

[See working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-huqdcr?file=src/app/pages/action-sheet/action-sheet.component.html)

```
::ng-deep .match-item-action-sheet{
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

::ng-deep .red{
    color:red;
}
```

[image]

**Edit!**
According image you attach to question

Set style to `.action-sheet-group.sc-ion-action-sheet-md`

In css:

```
::ng-deep .match-item-action-sheet .action-sheet-group.sc-ion-action-sheet-md{
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

::ng-deep .red .action-sheet-group.sc-ion-action-sheet-md{
    color:red!important;
}
```

Comment: border-radius did not work, try using mode=md to get a better view

Comment: Have a look at the image added in the question, that is what I want

Answer (score 0):

Write the following in your variables.scss:

```
.red {
  --color: red;
}
```

And the following in your component's scss:

```
.action-sheet-group {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Action Sheet Buttons color is controlled by the below class `.action-sheet-button.sc-ion-action-sheet-ios` or you can verify it in the browser inspector.

If you need only  change the  delete section use this class `.action-sheet-destructive.sc-ion-action-sheet-ios`.

Add your styles that are needed to be modified and place it the **variables.scss** as I have done below.

> .action-sheet-destructive.sc-ion-action-sheet-ios {
>     color: red;
>   }

Also, you have to change similarly to the relevant class in android.

Answer (score -1):

```
const actionSheet = await this.actionSheetController.create({
  mode: 'md',
  css-class: 'match-item-action-sheet red',
  }]
});
```

Try above code. Used `css-class` instead of `cssClass`.

Refer [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/action-sheet#methods) for above issue.

Comment: @SagarKodte Yes I already tried that as per the docs before posting question but it did not work